# Update the timestamp shown when an edit has been done in the 5-minute time frame

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface, timestamps

I edit a question of mine to change the punctuation and, as I am in my attention-deficit moment, I edited it after 2 minutes to change the punctuation of another sentence.

When I pressed the "Save Edits" button, the answer was reported to be changed two minutes ago, not (for example) 30 seconds ago.

[image: screenshot]

The timestamp of the last edit should be updated, in such cases.

Comment: I think there is a small window of time in which you have the ability to edit your edit and have it count as the same edit (such as hitting save, then realising you forgot to add the tag you were supposed to, or alter the title), I could be wrong.